# Nginx, la página principal carga, pero al intentar entrar en hiperenlaces cae en 404

Tags: nginx

Tengo un servidor nginx como distribuidor de carga y proxy inverso, hace bien en repartir carga, pero a la hora de añadirle una web simple, al intentar entrar en los hiperenlaces me salta un error 404, creo que el problema está en el repartidor de carga, este es su fichero de configuración:

```
upstream web {
    server 192.168.1.97:8081;
    server proyectodeasir.ddns.net:8082;
}
server {
    listen 8888 default_server;
    listen [::]:8888 default_server;


    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php;

    server_name asirproyect.ddns.net _;

location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri  / /index.php;
#       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?uri&$args;
#       try_files $uri $uri/ /login.php;
        proxy_pass http://web;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

En el mismo código están los intentos que he realizado.
Muchas gracias por su ayuda